# 1 values for 4 columns. Even though I've entered 4 values it is saying it is only working for one column

Tags: python

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("My database")
c = connection.cursor()


c.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Child (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name TEXT,
Age INTEGER
);
''')
c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Parent (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name TEXT,
Age INTEGER,
Child_ID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(Child_ID) REFERENCES Child(ID)
);
''')

connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
c.execute('''
INSERT INTO Child (Name, Age)  VALUES (
"Armaan",17
)
''')
connection.commit()

params2 = (1,"Mum",46,1)
c.execute('''
INSERT INTO Parent (ID , Name , Age , Child_ID) VALUES (
(?,?,?,?)
)
''',params2)


connection.commit()
```

I can't tell where I've gone wrong. I've lookede at answers for similar to this question but can't find a suitable answer:
Error:
sqlite3 OperationalError: 1 values for 4 columns

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute('''
INSERT INTO Parent (ID , Name , Age , Child_ID) VALUES (
(?,?,?,?)
)
''',params2)
```

Why do you have an extra layer of parentheses inside the `VALUES` clause?  Take that out.